# Phonegap app not opening external link on click

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

I am new to PhoneGap and Cordova. I am trying to create an application for now just for personal purposes.

### The problem:

When I run the app on the phonegap desktop I can easily open the links when I press the desired content (#first). But when I upload app on build.phonegap and then download the app on a phone it does not work anymore.

Also I'm getting the error: `Error initializing Cordova: Class not found`

---

Here is my content from github: https://github.com/unforgivenJ/Test

And app for download: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/2182437/share

Any help would be appreciated. Regards, Miha.

Comment: Add whitelist plugin to your project

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, but the whitelist plugin is already added to project: 

this the plugin list from the cli:

cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 1.2.1 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-device-orientation 1.0.3 "Device Orientation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.3.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"

Comment: Update the config.xml in your question

Comment: I noticed that i have to have different config.xml file in the project folder and change some attributes. Now it's working!